# A case for catching a generic Exception in Python?

Tags: python, exception

There is a simple scenario that I seem to encounter quite often: I invoke a function that can raise any number of exceptions. I won't do anything different if it is one exception versus another, I just want to log the exception information and either re-raise the exception or indicate in some other way that something didn't go as planned (such as returning None), otherwise proceed normally. So I use some form of the exception handling shown below.

Please note:

- Imagine his code is running in a daemon that processes messages, so it needs to keep running, even if one of the messages causes some kind of exception.
- I am aware that there is a rule of thumb that it is not generally advisable to catch a generic Exception because that may hide specfic errors that should be handled differently. (This is true in other languages as well.) This case is different because I don't care what exception is raised, the handling is the same.

Is there a better way?

```
def my_func(p1):                                                                
    retval = None                                                            
    try:                                                                        
        valx = other_func1(p1)                                                  
    except Exception as ex:                                                     
        log.error('other_func1 failed. {}: {}'.format(type(ex).__name__, ex))   
    else:                                                                       
        retval = ...                                                            
    return retval
```

Comment: That seems decent, actually.

Comment: aside, you can [`log.exception()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) inside an `except` suite and make your calls a bit simpler.  Usually just `log.exception("something bad happened")` and the logging system will format the traceback itself for you.

Comment: I would note that if the best answer is `except Exception as ex/:` then you are most likely asking a wrong question and have serious design issues in whatever you are doing. And the exceptions of that I can count on single hand. In case of a daemon this would, potentially, also suppress an error which indicates that it cannot spawn more worker threads, so it will not work and for you it will be yet-another-generic-exception.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul, are you saying that there are non-system-exiting Exceptions that would not be caught here? Also, I don't understand how the answer by KSFT has a checkmark next to it. At least I didn't intend to mark it that way. (Noob here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way?

Doubt it, Python has these built-in Base Exception Classes so creating something on your own is really just being redundant. If you handle everything in the same way, generalizing in your `except` with `Exception` is most likely the best way to tackle this.

*Small caveat here:* **[`Exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#Exception)** isn't the most general you can get, from the documentation:

> All built-in, non-system-exiting exceptions are derived from this class. All user-defined exceptions should also be derived from this class.

So, it won't catch **all** exceptions:

```
In [4]: try:
   ...:     raise SystemExit
   ...: except Exception as b:
   ...:     print("Catch All")
To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit
```

Which, do note, is of course something you should want. A `SystemExit` should exit. But, if some edge case requires it, to also catch system-exiting exceptions you can use **[`BaseException`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException)** which is as loose as you can get with exception matching:

```
In [2]: try:
   ...:     raise SystemExit
   ...: except BaseException as b:
   ...:     print("Catch All")
Catch All
```

Use it at your own discretion but, **it probably makes zero sense to actually use it**, and this case does not seem to require it. I just mentioned it because it is the most general you can get. I believe the way you have done it is more than sufficient.

Comment: it seems unwise to catch system-exiting-exceptions, since I would think they are things like out-of-memory, in which case it would be dangerous to continue doing anything.

Comment: Totally agree. Just threw it out there as the "most general".

Answer (score -1):

That looks like a fine way to catch them if you're handling them all the same way. <s>If you want to check what kind of exception was raised, you can use the built-in function `type` and compare the result to an exception class (for example, one from [the list of built-in exception types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html)):</s>

```
try:
    f()
except Exception as ex:
    if type(ex)==ValueError:
        handle_valueerror()
    else:
        handle_other_exception()
```

If you're handling them differently, use `except <SpecificExceptionClass>`. I'm not sure what I was thinking before.

Comment: But then you could just use specific excepts before the broad one, [as python supports it just fine](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Downvoting over style? Wow.

Comment: @Zizouz212 this isn't matter of just style but also reinventing the wheel, why do that when there is a native support for a better solution? Or is that all constructive you had to add here?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Wow, I'm not sure what I was thinking. That was a really stupid way to do that.

Comment: @KSFT we are all here to learn, which is why I always leave a comment whenever I down vote something :).

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul, if I intend to handle all the exceptions in the same way, what advantage is there in specifying all known-at-the-time-of-writing Exceptions?